# Spark shuts down after 10 seconds of running

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to setup clusters in my AWS account (Amazon). I followed [this](https://www.supergloo.com/fieldnotes/apache-spark-cluster-amazon-ec2-tutorial/) tutorial to set it up. I've ran into some problems regarding ports but I finally got it to work until... it shut down after 10 seconds giving me no more than this error:

> 16/05/12 12:52:46 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master spark://ip-to-my-machine:7077...
>
> 16/05/12 12:53:06 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master spark://ip-to-my-machine:7077...
>
> 16/05/12 12:53:26 ERROR cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
>
> 16/05/12 12:53:26 ERROR scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Exiting due to error from cluster scheduler: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.

This was the bash I ran to make it work:

```
bin/spark-shell --master spark://ip-to-my-machine:7077
```

I opened the TCP port 7077, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: are u able to ping ur ip <ip-to-my-machine>

Comment: login ur machine and check it spark is master is running or not